# Get only child nodes of a parent node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I try to work with html agility pack. The basic works fine, only when I try to get the childnodes of a part, then i dont get all nodes with this the class 'dealer-offer' equal in which parentnode it will be.

Here is the code, that i use for it:

```
private void getListOfDiv(string html, string classname)
    {

        if (html != null)
        {

            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            var divProduktkategorie = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='" + classname + "']");

            //this.txtHtmlCode.Text = divProduktkategorie.InnerHtml;
            //return;
            int i = 1;

            foreach( var divAngebote in divProduktkategorie.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dealer-offer']"))
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(i + ": " + classname);
                this.txtHtmlCode.AppendText(divAngebote.OuterHtml);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Wenn I return the divProduktkategorie to the outputfild, then I get only the 3 positiones, which be under this singlenode, but wenn I start the loop, then I get every node with the class 'dealer-offer' and not only the 3 positions.

Where is my fault? I didn't find it by myself.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the 3 nodes with correct relative path and then just foreach them. Dont search them in divProduktkategorie references.

```
private void getListOfDiv(string html, string classname)
{

    if (html != null)
    {

        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var divProduktkategorie = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='" + classname + "']//div[@class='dealer-offer']");

        //this.txtHtmlCode.Text = divProduktkategorie.InnerHtml;
        //return;
        int i = 1;

        foreach( var divAngebote in divProduktkategorie)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(i + ": " + classname);
            this.txtHtmlCode.AppendText(divAngebote.OuterHtml);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```